# Fedora 30 and tp-link wireless stick

Tags: fedora, wifi

I am booting Fedora 30 on a live USB and my wireless stick (tp-link TL-WN821N) cannot seem to connect to my wifi. The stick does work on Ubuntu, however.

I am wondering if it's a driver issue, but the thing is the stick is working, identifies properly available wifi networks, etc. It's just that when I try to connect, it just can't seem to pick up the connection, giving me the error "Activation of network connection failed".

Could it be because I'm using the live boot on the USB? Any ideas how to solve this? I'm otherwise loving Fedora 30 so far... I just wish I could use wifi on it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking here; but if you also check https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/questions/ you may find an answer there.